# How to properly use DoThrow()

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Just start unit-testing currently, so I have two questions regarding this error within this question, I hope its ok.

1. I have a class that has one positive test and three negative tests and one of this negative case is using doThrow to simulate failed repository, but it also causes the positive test to fail, is there any way to fix this?
2. Ideally, do the negative case and positive case must be separated into two class?

I already googled about this but can't find any reference or even the same problem as me, already ask on discord, while I do find some fix for it, by making new class JUST for the negative doThrow case, but i'm looking for additional opinion.

here is  the example of the negative case

```
@Test(expected = DAOException.class)
    public void testFail() throws ObjectNotEncypted, ObjectNotFound {
        List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>();
        ids.add(id);

        Mockito.when(tempRepo.tempfunction(var)).thenReturn(Optional.of(expectedvalue));
        Mockito.when(tempRepo.tempfunction(var)).thenReturn(expectedvalue);
        Mockito.when(tempRepo.tempfunction(var)).thenReturn(null);
        Mockito.when(tempRepo.tempfunction(var)).thenReturn(1);
        Mockito.when(tempRepo.tempfunction(var)).thenReturn(1);
        Mockito.doThrow(DAOException.class).when(tempRepo).tempfunctionthatshouldfail(var);

        service.dofunction(ids);
    }
```

-- ADDITIONAL CODE
heres how i construct the config and declare the variable

```
@Configuration
    static class classConfig {
        @Bean
        public service accountService() {
            return new serviceImpl();
        }

        @Bean
        public TempRepo tempRepo () {
            return Mockito.mock(TempRepo.class);
        }
}

@Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Autowired
    private TempRepo tempRepo ;
```

The expected result is all test cases should run, but i got one error, and the trace only one line, its this `com.project.common.exception.DAOException`
and this is the positive case part of the code.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just trying it out again, after some debugging, for some reason my negatif case run BEFORE the positive case, thankfully theres order annotation for junit, since i use JUnit 4, i use order based on class name, but if you use Junit 5, you can use order by number, ex `@Order(1)` , and it works like intended now

just to be clear, solution with `@Before` and resetting the mock each time for some reason didn't work even thought technically it should work

Answer (score 4):

I noticed your `tempRepo` is a global variable, have you tried invoking `Mockito.reset(tempRepo);`?

And how do you initialise `tempRepo` mock? Using the annotation `@Mock` or in the constructor via `Mockito.mock(Repo.class)`?

Or could you share your test class here?

Comment: If you do not have enough information from the OP to answer - this should not be an answer but a comment asking for clarification.

Comment: while i can't share the whole code, but i put additional info on how i made the config and declaring the var, and i also already use the Mockito.reset which unfortunately doesnt work

Comment: @Solid_Metal, but your `tempRepo` variable is injected? If it is intentionally to be mocked, could you try to reinitialise the mock for every test cases, like:
`
@Before
public initTempRepo() {
  tempRepo = Mockito.mock(TempRepo.class);
}
`

Comment: @Solid_Metal, just another thought, are you sure that the exception is caused by the mocking? Have you tried solely running the positive test case and it passes? Unless the positive test case is executing the line tempRepo.tempfunctionthatshouldfail(), otherwise it shouldn't fail, should it? :)

Comment: @aheryan i already tried the `@before`, but it even worse, it cause failure to everything on the test, and yes, i can confirmed, since if i comment the negative case, everything run just fine, 
the problem is the positive case should executing the tempRepo.tempfunctionthatshouldfail(), while its indeed not returning any value, but i think i still need to access it for saying "hey this work correctly", but theres cases where tempRepo.tempfunctionthatshouldfail() fail to run, thats where the doThrow comes in

Comment: well not returning any value is probably incorrect, it does returning value, but its not something that is checked again on the code, but still need to be mocked to avoid chance of error on the tested function

Comment: Sorry @Solid_Metal, I've run out of clue. But one last try - try invoking `Mockito.reset(tempRepo)` in `@Before`? Meaning for each test case you clear the mocking/stubbing and start fresh.